# Roles Required to Start/Stop Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, cloud, virtual-machine

What are the roles required for the following

- Start/Stop the VM
- Connect to VM using Remote Desktop.I tried connecting with the IP the owner provided but i cannot connect.I have also tried viewing the Public IP but can't see anything in the Public IP field nor there i can see details under networking tab.

Comment: Does the VM have a public IP? Do you see the public Ip enabled from networking tab- network interface- IP configuration- ipconfig1?

Comment: @NancyXiong I can't see the Public IP nor i can access the network panel...I have asked the Owner to assign me the VM Contributor Role,still i can't see the IP.

Comment: can you assign the VM Contributor Role on the resource group level instead of the VM itself? The below answer is clear.

Comment: @NancyXiong I will ask the owner and get back..

Answer (score 1):

1: You could use the builtin role: VM Contributor, or if you want to scope it down even farther by making a custom role. *
2: There can be multiple reasons: Firewall blocks you, there is no public IP attached to the NIC, or perhaps the permissions are incorrect. So for your permissions you might need to be added as contributor (default role) on the resource group, or it can even be scoped down to just contirbutor on the VM itself.

- In custom roles you can add as many resource provider operations as you want. These operations will define your permissions on the resources in Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations
  Have a look at for example: Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines
  You will see many operations, including PowerOff/action
  usually people tend to use the default roles, but I prefer making custom role templates to prevent possible security concerns.

Comment: Thanks .. I can't see the Public IP nor i can access the network panel...I have asked the Owner to assign me the VM Contributor Role,still i can't see the IP.

Comment: Verify your permission on the VM so the customer has given you the correct permission. https://ibb.co/52DNt10 . And also you need to refresh your browser or log out/ log in after you get new permission.

Comment: I have got VM Contributor Role and Reader role.. still i cannot see the IP

Comment: Are you realy sure you have the VM contributor role? It qualifies for everything you need to see. Is it not by chance something less privileged? I have had a few cases where permissions that got applied weren't effective immediatly, also you could actually scale up to contributor instead of vm contributor. If that doesn't fixes it: Maybe it's being executed incorrectly, or the scope is incorrect. Did you try logging in via a private browser, so it's not the browser derping you?

Comment: @Marco I think it might be a scope issue.. Anyways he has now created a `FQDN` now and i can access it using the URL without the IP... Thanks for your help